# Install Matlab R2011a in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from -.iso

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, matlab

I cant install Matlab. I have a ISO file (ml2011au.iso - 4.3 Gb), have the Furius ISO Mount, and access as root in terminal with the command `gksudo gnome-terminal`. I'm using a 32-bit PC.

1. I Mount the iso with Furius.
2. Hit `gksudo gnome-terminal` which open a new window where I access to the mounted files and i found two important files: (1) the install file - can't open or access because is read only (2) a file named `Installer_Input.txt` with instructions. I follow instructions (put the Path, the Key, standalone, etc) but I'm not sure about using this file to **trigger installation**.

I installed Matlab few months ago and can't remember how I used this installer. It's a .txt, and the first instruction is:  copy this file and uncomment the lines you have to change.

When I hit (inside the .iso folder) `./install` or `sudo ./install` or`sudo chmod ./install`. Some people with the same issue did making the java file in `/matlab-extracted-folder/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/` executable using `chmod +x ./java`. I did this, but, there is no folder named `/sys/` inside the .iso; there is a `/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/` so I did it on this file. Still can't execute install.